# How to iterate through every pages in a word document using apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Are there any functions in apache poi that lets you iterate through every page in a word document? Similar to HSLF component where you can access every slide content in a powerpoint file?

Comment: Are you aware that the Microsoft Word file formats are, unlike PDF, run-based and not page-based?

Comment: I see. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to iterate through each page in a word document but I have written this code that extracts all the sections using poi and jSoup:

```
   private List<String> extractListOfSections() {

        String content = parse.getXMLHandler().toString();
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
        List<Element> link = doc.select("h, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");

        List<String> headings = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Element element : link) {
            if (element.text() != null) {
                headings.add(element.text().replaceAll("\\p{P}", " "));
            }
        }

        return headings;

    }
```

I then used this list to extract the contents of each section.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the solution instead considering what @Gagravarr had said.

Comment: This is a very lengthy answer if what you want is to iterate over the whole document. you can use the getParagraphs() to loop through all document paragraphs